# Assembly language programs in linux using amd64

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm, x86-64, gnu-assembler

Do i need to use AT & T syntax(GAS) or Intel syntax or anything else for writing assembly language program in linux with AMD 64 bit architecture using NASM ? What is the instruction set used to run AMD64? Does it support push pop instructions?

Answer (score 1):

NASM uses intel syntax. Available instructions can be found from AMD manual: http://amd-dev.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wordpress/media/2008/10/24594_APM_v3.pdf

Comment: Can you suggest some beginners tutorial to learn assembly language and code in NASM using INTEL SYNTAX

Comment: @user3264821 This tutorial contains some useful examples on how to write programs in linux and how to use C functions so you don't have to write everything in assembly: [http://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/nasmexamples/](http://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/nasmexamples/)

Comment: I learn something like this:                              section .text
    global _start   ;must be declared for linker (ld)
_start:             ;tells linker entry point
    mov edx,len     ;message length
    mov ecx,msg     ;message to write
    mov ebx,1       ;file descriptor (stdout)
    mov eax,4       ;system call number (sys_write)
    int 0x80        ;call kernel
 
    mov eax,1       ;system call number (sys_exit)
    int 0x80        ;call kernel

section .data
msg db 'Hello, world!', 0xa  ;our dear string
len equ $ - msg              ;length of our dear string

Comment: could you suggest some books